# Uneven cell heights in final row of GridLayoutManaged RecylerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a recycler view that can have it's layout manager changed with the click of a button. It can cycle through some LinearLayout managed stuff and some GridLayout managed items. They both work fine, but the on the grid views, the final row always has uneven heights.

Not the end of the world, but I'd like to fix it.

The cells have dynamic height based on the content length of the title of the game.

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrSbO.jpg)

Many users with similar problems were due to constraint layouts, but I don't have any in these particular views

Here is one of the XMLs that represents my grid cell.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_marginDiv2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_marginDiv2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cell_side_marginDiv2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cell_side_marginDiv2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_paddingDiv2"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_paddingDiv2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cell_side_paddingDiv2"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cell_side_paddingDiv2"
            android:id="@+id/large_game_list_row_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/foreground" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/ownership_tag_on_cell"
                    android:id="@+id/ownershipTagLayout"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </include>

                <!--Console Image and Name-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/consoleArtImageView"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:contentDescription="Console Art"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_console_decorator_image_box_dimension"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_console_decorator_image_box_dimension" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/cell_element_spacingDiv2"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                        android:id="@+id/consoleNameTextView"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="name"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/list_item_console_decorator_image_text_size" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />

            <!--Box art-->
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/list_item_placeholder"
                android:id="@+id/boxArtImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_medium_image_box_dimension"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2.5dp"
                android:contentDescription="BoxArt"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <!--Metadata (title, developer, action button)-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstLineTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    tools:text="Title"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cell_small_grid_title_text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_padding" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/firstSubLineTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/cell_subtitle_text_size"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    tools:text="Dev"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/cell_top_bottom_padding">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/statusTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cell_element_spacingDiv2"
                    android:background="@drawable/ownership_bubble_background"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bubble_top_bottom_padding"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bubble_side_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/bubble_side_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/bubble_top_bottom_padding"
                    tools:text="status"
                    android:textColor="@color/bubble_ownership_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bubble_text_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/priceTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/price_bubble_background_gradient"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bubble_top_bottom_padding"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/bubble_side_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/bubble_side_padding"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/bubble_top_bottom_padding"
                    tools:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="@color/bubble_price_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/bubble_text_size" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Including some code might help

Comment: Added the XML. Everything else is standard stuff but I'll definitely add anything else you think is relevant!